# List Hibernate configuration parametrs

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

Is there a way to programatically get Hibernate configuration parameter values, if I have access to a SessionFactory object?

I would like to list the configuration in a GUI view, for debuging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast your `SessionFactory` into the concrete `SessionFactoryImpl` implementation, then you'll have access to the properties coming from the `Configuration` through [`getProperties()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/javadocs/org/hibernate/impl/SessionFactoryImpl.html#getProperties()).

Comment: Thx Pascal! Properties field is private in SessionFactoryImpl, I couldn't find a getter path to it, so I ripped it out with reflection, but it's working. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @Robert In Hibernate 3.5, there is `getProperties()` which is public. That's the version on which I based my answer. I don't have any better suggestion than reflection for previous versions.